# ASCII converter without system.text library in C#

Tags: c#, encoding, arrays, ascii, mvvmcross

I have to convert string to ascii byte array.

How can I replace the following command when I don't have access to ASCII in `system.text`? This library is limited in mvvmcross framework.

```
byte[] byteArray = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(dataString);
```

I have access only to:

```
Encoding.UTF8
Encoding.Unicode
Encoding.BigEndianUnicode
```

not to

```
Encoding.ASCII
```

Comment: Where do you get the input string from and for what purpose are you converting to Ascii?

Comment: To converting POST data in HttpWebRequest.

Comment: Ok, just be aware that you should do proper sanitisation of the POST parameters, if you're not using static text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply use

```
var byteArray = dataString.Select(x => (byte)x).ToArray();
```